# Excel sort and filter to make a chart

Tags: vba

I'm trying to create a program through excel that will sort through a list of names and once it finds all the same names it has to sort on a certain type then once it gets that it has to sort on an ID then total up the hours based on that name type and ID and I have to do this alot of time...then create a chart. I have never used VBA before what is the best way?

Comment: Why would you use VBA ? You can use a pivot chart or pivot table + chart.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can use PivotTables for this. Check http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/08/19/excel-pivot-tables-tutorial/ for a tutorial.
If you wish to learn some VBA, you can check http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html.
Another useful way is to record your actions as a macro and look at the auto-generated code.